# What's the meaning of Quidway display vlan out log?

Tags: networking, router, vlan

In the Quidway AR2220 router, when I display vlan:

```
[Huawei]display vlan 
The total number of vlans is : 1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
U: Up;         D: Down;         TG: Tagged;         UT: Untagged;
MP: Vlan-mapping;               ST: Vlan-stacking;
#: ProtocolTransparent-vlan;    *: Management-vlan;
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

VID  Type    Ports                                                          
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

1    common  UT:GE0/0/1(U)      GE0/0/2(D)      GE0/0/3(D)      GE0/0/4(D)      
                GE0/0/5(D)      GE0/0/6(D)      GE0/0/7(D)      GE0/0/8(D)      
                GE0/0/9(D)      GE0/0/10(D)     GE0/0/11(D)     GE0/0/12(D)     
                GE0/0/13(D)     GE0/0/14(D)     GE0/0/15(D)     GE0/0/16(D)     
                GE0/0/17(D)     GE0/0/18(D)     GE0/0/19(D)     GE0/0/20(D)     
                GE0/0/21(D)     GE0/0/22(D)     GE0/0/23(D)     GE0/0/24(D)     


VID  Status  Property      MAC-LRN Statistics Description      
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

1    enable  default       enable  disable    VLAN 0001
```

I have several questions:

1) I do not understand the `MAC-LRN` and `Statistics` meaning.
2) What's the meaning of `Vlan-mapping` and `Vlan-stacking`?
3) What's the meaning of `ProtocolTransparent-vlan` and `Management-vlan`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Complete shots in the dark based on what I know from Cisco routers. Maybe somebody can correct me. I am sure Huawei documentation exists for all, this I have never use Huawei stuff before.

MAC-LRN: Enable/disable for learning the paths to various MAC addresses. I have never disabled this but I am sure somebody has come up with a reason to flood every packet on every port member of a VLAN.

Vlan-mapping: This is used on Trunk Ports. Indicates that this VLAN does not use its VLAN ID as its VLAN tag on this trunk port. Instead it uses a different tag. This is useful for transporting customer VLANs to different endpoints over a network that already has several VLANs. Your customers may not use the same VLAN IDs as you do.

Vlan-stacking: This is essentially double-tagging support. It is used for the same reason as mapping, it's just an alternate approach.

ProtocolTransparent-vlan: VLAN Trunk Protocol (VTP) reduces administration in a switched network. When you configure a new VLAN on one VTP server, the VLAN is distributed through all switches in the domain. This reduces the need to configure the same VLAN everywhere. VTP transparent switches do not participate in VTP. A VTP transparent switch does not advertise its VLAN configuration and does not synchronize its VLAN configuration based on received advertisements, but transparent switches do forward VTP advertisements that they receive out their trunk ports in VTP Version 2

Management-vlan: Management (e.g. accessing the Terminal/CLI) is only allowed on certain vlans and certain ports.